SQL sort for name with favorites on top
I have a list with sort filters. Based on the parameter, I want it to show the favorites with that parameter on top while keeping them sorted by name (if on the same value):
Example 1: Order from A-Z

Alissa(*)
Frank(*)
Jessica(*)
Anna
Bob
Jack
Zack

Example 2: Order from last invoice

Jessica(*) /2024
Alissa(*)  /2023
Frank(*) /2021
Jack /2024
Zack /2024
Anna /2023
Bob /2023

I tried
    `ORDER BY 
             favorite ${sortDirection}, name ${sortDirection}`

also
`ORDER BY 
        favorite DESC,
        CASE WHEN favorite = 1 THEN ${orderBy} END ${sortDirection},
        CASE WHEN favorite = 1 THEN name END ASC,
        CASE WHEN favorite = 0 THEN ${orderBy} END ${sortDirection},
        CASE WHEN favorite = 0 THEN name END ASC
    `;

${sortDirection} can be ASC or DESC. But in this case the favorites are shown from true to false, and they don't get sorted by name from A to Z but they have the same order they have in the database rows.

How about ORDER BY favorite DESC, ${orderBy} ${sortDirection} assuming orderBy contains the column you want to sort after sorting by favorite?

I suggest you include sample data.

Provide a complete [mcve], i.e. both sample table data and the expected result.

For the first example, I think you want something like:
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    favorite DESC,   -- favorite = 1 sorts first, favorite = 0 second
    name;            -- then sort each sub group by name


In the second edit the favorites are not sorted by name, but they're just displayed in the order they have in the db.

@Filippo Tables have no inherent ordering. If you don't have a column to order on then you can't do this.
